# UITableViewCell editingAccessory too far right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

Today I observed, that my editingAccessory (`UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton`) is too far on the right side, when the my tableView is in editing mode.

When toggling editing on and off I can see the icon move from their regular position to where they are in editing.

In my implementation I'm using

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT**

There is no more code. It's just a plain `UITableViewController` and the edit button runs noting but the default `-setEditing:animated:` behind the scenes (as far as I can tell).

**EDIT II**

Find the complete [ViewController implementation here](https://gist.github.com/julian-weinert/5059916f4f87ffe0178e)

[image: editing accessory glitch]

Comment: what is the code for the Edit button action?

Comment: It's the default iOS implementation as it is

Comment: Do you reload or use different cell setup when in edit mode? Looks like a layout against margin type issue as the right hand side seems to move right slightly.

Comment: I added a gist to show my viewController

Comment: To answer your question, @RoryMcKinnel, No, I don't. I return the cell as it is returned by `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: @Julian Try setting `cell.indentationLevel=0;` after you deque the cell. The default for that seems to be 10pts.

Comment: Nope, didn't do the trick, unfortunately. But it's actually not indented. Indentation is always from left (correct?) but the cell gets shrieked from the right...

Comment: What happens if you return YES for indent on edit but set the indent width to 0. Odd but might work.

Comment: Then it indents by the default amount. Does not matter what I do, I don't get rid of it.

Comment: Actually the DetailButton is meant to move out of the screen towards right and disappear while editing and come back when editing is done. But since you have set Editing Accessory as Detail it remains there and is pushed a little rightwards. If you just keep the Accessory as Detail and set the Editing Accessory as None you can feel the difference. I suppose it is meant for showing detail and isn't required during editing.

Comment: It's absolutely required during editing in my scenario. Otherwise I wouldn't have added it as editing accessory. The question remains: Why is the editing accessory shifted and how to get it in the "right" position. I'll might get around with creating another bool (editing and alternative or so) if there is no possibility to do so OOTB

Comment: Then custom xib & creating outlets for each cell element and then setting their frames while editing is the only solution I can think of now. Anyway do post your solution if you figure it out. Best of luck!